# eSun Silk Rainbow PLA leads to nozzle clogging

Tags: pla, extruder, nozzle, print-failure, dremel-3d45

I use eSUN (Silk) PLA filament daily and I've never had an issue. I use the parameters suggested by the manufacturer:

- nozzle temperature: 210 °C
- bed temperature: 60 °C (with purple glue)

The extrusions are perfects (the printing itself may be improved, but here I'm talking about the extrusion) even if it runs for 20h+.

Instead with the [Silk Rainbow PLA](https://www.amazon.it/eSUN-Arcobaleno-Multicolore-Precisione-Dimensionale/dp/B081Q78248) filament, after few hours the extruder is clogged. No more extrusion. I have to stop the printing (and waste all) preheat the extruder, remove the nozzle and extract the filament. Then, feeding another kind of PLA I'm able to recover the functionality.

This happens ONLY with this specific filament!

I tried to increase the nozzle temperature up to 220 °C. It lasted maybe one hour longer but eventually failed again.

The filament is stored inside a dryer that is on during printing.
What can cause such a behavior? I have a Dremel 3D45.

### UPDATE

Here some pictures. Some parts are broken because I had already thrown it away. The bottom layer is quite good:

[image]

Details of the surface of the base:

[image]
[image]

Details of the infill and support structures:

[image]

Weird enough both the comment and the answer suggest to lower the temperature but here the answer I received from the manufacturer:

> You can adjust the printing temperature to 230 °C higher, and then
> adjust the printing speed to 40 mm/s slower. The plug is generally
> caused by bad material fluidity, the temperature is set higher, you
> can increase the fluidity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you lower the temperature. There's a different sweet spot for some filaments even if they're the same brand. And it's not always the middle recommended heat on the label I have found.

Comment: Question updated, the manufacturer suggests to higher the temperature. Do you find a rationale in this hint?

Comment: @Mark the op already tried that, making it lower is the next logical troubleshooting measure. It's what has worked for me in the past.

Comment: I am the OP. Actually I only raised the temperature to 220 °C, while eSun suggests to reach 230 °C instead of lowering it. What I mean is: why *try* at random temperatures instead of understand which is the problem and (at least) change the temperature in the right direction?

Comment: @Mark good luck

Comment: @Mark the solution is: print a temperature tower.